# Why is my second <select> tag is not showing up?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to display `<select id="second_choice">` tag after I choose one of the options in `<select id="first_choice">`. Both are selected from my database.

technician.php

```
<select name="cntNum" id="first_choice" class="form-control" onchange="fetch_select(this.value);" required>
  <?php 
    include('config.php');
    $query = "SELECT cntNum FROM contract";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option>".$row{'cntNum'}."</option>";
    }                                                                                       
</select>
<select name="cntNum" id="second_choice" class="form-control" required></select>
```

technician_fetch.php

```
require_once( 'config.php' );

$choice = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['choice']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE cntNum = $choice";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option>" . $row{'cntNum'} . "</option>";
}
```

jQuery

```
<script>
  $("#first_choice").change(function () {
    $("#second_choice").load("technician_fetch.php?choice=" + $( "#first_choice").val());
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to close your PHP before writing anymore HTML.

```
<select name="cntNum" id="first_choice" class="form-control" onchange="fetch_select(this.value);" required>
  <?php 
    include('config.php');
    $query = "SELECT cntNum FROM contract";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option>".$row{'cntNum'}."</option>";
    }
  ?>
<!-- PHP must be closed if you then continue with HTML -->                                                                                       
</select>
<select name="cntNum" id="second_choice" class="form-control" required></select>
```

If you are just writing PHP in a file then you don't need to close it but if you have a different language after it (HTML) you must close it.

Comment: hi jacc_01, I actually left the close bracket when I copied the code here. It's still not working.

Comment: Ah, okay. Just to clarify, when you say the second `<select>` tag is not showing up, you mean that when you select an option in the first `<select>`, the whole second `<select>` element doesn't show up or just the dropdown values?

Comment: Also, you aren't setting the value of any `<option>` elements in the first `<select>` you are only setting the text that is shown to the user. Try setting the `value` attribute of each `<option>` to the value returned from the SQL query.

Comment: 1) Just the dropdown values didnt show up. 2) I have tried to echo "<option value=$row{'cntNum'}>".$row{'cntNum'}."</option>"; and it's still not working. Couldn't figure out anything else.

Comment: This shouldn't be the problem but just to be safe could you append ":selected" to `#first_choice` where you've written `("#first_choice").val()`